# Has String.Intern had the value?

Tags: c#, .net, string-interning

`String.Intern` has a special pool for strings which can later be retrieved.

Is there any way for me to know that the specified string **was** taken from the pool , and was NOt newly created ?
example :

```
string s1 = "MyTest"; 
string s2 = new StringBuilder().Append("My").Append("Test").ToString(); 
string s3 = String.Intern(s2); 
Console.WriteLine((Object)s2==(Object)s1); // Different references.
Console.WriteLine((Object)s3==(Object)s1); // The same reference.
```

s3 ref val **was** taken from the pool

is there any way for me to know it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have some luck with the `IsInterned` method, it returns `null` if the string wasn't interned, and returns a reference if it was taken from the pool. However, this behaviour will depend on the runtime, and might not yield what you expect.

Answer (score 4):

I think that IsInterned method could help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use `String.IsInterned()`.

See the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned.aspx).