# How do you create a String object

Tags: java, oop

I don't understand why you create a String object as follows:

```
String stringObj = "";
```

I think, it should be:

```
String obj = new String();
```

Comment: It should be noted that there is no need to initialize your "stringObj" reference variable when you declare it.  So long as a value is eventually assigned to it before you use it somewhere, you can simply say `String stringObj;`.  When a new value is assigned to "stringObj", it is a reference to a different object -- it's not modifying the String that the variable may have previously referenced.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison, compare?!

Comment: Covers the same subjects.  Am I wrong in this? Perhaps it is not truly duplicate, I will remove flag.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison, Oh I see, both have common with string interning. Excuse me

Comment: I will leave it be.  This question may appear on some searches the other would not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String stringObj = "";
```

Is called as `String` literals. They are [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

What that means is, let us say if you have

```
String stringObj = "";
String stringObj2 = "";
String stringObj3 = "";
```

All 3 references (`stringObj`, `stringObj2`, `stringObj3`) points to same memory location.

```
String obj = new String();
```

This syntax creates new `String` object on every invocation.

What that means is, let us say if you have:

```
String stringObj = new String();
String stringObj2 = new String();
String stringObj3 = new String();
```

Three new (separate) `String` objects will be created and point to *different* memory locations.

Comment: you can explain more detail for me?

Comment: As an aside, I wouldn't worry about whether or not two String objects point to the same memory location (since you can't modify them anyway).  Thus, don't use == to compare strings.  Use `s1.equals(s2)`.

Answer (score 4):

Java compiler has special syntax for creating string objects from string literals. When you write

```
String stringObj = "";
```

Java creates a new `String` object, ans assigns it to `stringObj`.

Note that this is not directly equivalent to `new String()`, because strings instantiated from string literals are [*interned*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8688300/335858). This means that strings created from the same literal are not only object-equal, but also reference-equal (i.e. reference the same object).